# D3 : get value from the array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Firstly, I declared a `var Dataset[];`

Then, I extract some values from the CSV file and then using `push()` to put the values(attributes are University, State, Salary, Type) in the Dataset.

I tried `console.log(Dataset)` and it works.

The result shows below: 
[image: Dataset value]

But when I tried 
    `console.log(Dataset.Salary)`
It shows an undefined error.

How can I get the Salary value of the Dataset array? cause I need to use it to show the bar chart for each university.
Appreciate.

Comment: Try `Dataset[0].Salary` and you'll see a value. `Salary` is not a property of the array, but a property of *each object* inside that array instead. Not related to your question, but here's a tip: loading the CSV with `d3.csv` just to populate another array is a waste of resources... just use the array `d3.csv` creates. Finally, use camelCase in JavaScript.

Comment: To get a particular `Salary` you can do `Dataset[<some_index>].Salary`. To get an array with all salaries, you can use `map()` as: `let salaries = Dataset.map(({Salary}) => Salary);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an array of objects, there are multiple different salary values. To get an individual value that belongs to an object, you must first reference the position of the object element in the array, and then the value you want; ie if you wanted the salary from the first object in the array, you would go:

```
Dataset[0].Salary
```

And if you wanted all of the salaries, you could do a for loop and iterate through all array elements...

```
for (var i = 0; i < Dataset.length; i++) {
  console.log(Dataset[i].Salary);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `int` is not JavaScript - use `var` (or better, `let`).

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong gramma, you should use Dataset[0].Salary exp.